# Converting a bitmap to bytearray to be displayed on an e-paper

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, bitmap

so I have to convert a bitmap that is 400x300 into a byte array with exactly 15000 size. It has to be displayed on an e-paper screen so it can only be black/white/gray.

This is my attempt so far:

```
fun convertPictureToByteArray(bitmap: Bitmap): ByteArray {
        val byteArray = ByteArray(15000)
        var index = 0
        var temp = 0

        val pixels = IntArray(bitmap.width * bitmap.height)
        bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.width, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height)
        for(x in (bitmap.height - 1) downTo 0) {
            for(y in 0 until bitmap.width / 8) {
                var tempPixels = IntArray(8)
                for(z in 0 until 8) {
                    tempPixels[z] = pixels[temp]
                    temp++
                }
                var totalLuminance = 0.0
                for(pixel in tempPixels) {
                    val red = Color.red(pixel)
                    val green = Color.green(pixel)
                    val blue = Color.blue(pixel)

                    val luminance = 0.299 * red + 0.587 * green + 0.114 * blue
                    totalLuminance += luminance
                }

                val averageLuminance = totalLuminance / tempPixels.size
                byteArray[index] = grayShadesArray[averageLuminance.toInt()]
                index++
            }
        }

        return byteArray
    }
```

Basically what it should do is go through the bitmap pixel by pixel and get average luminance from 8 pixels that are next to each other. Based on the average luminance I get byte value from greyShadesArray with that index and save it to a byte array I return. It kinda works but not well enough. There are white lines and text is not readable:
[Converted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjXmc.jpg)

Any suggestions on fixing it or other approaches are much appreciated!

Comment: It seems all wrong ... I bet e-paper is 1-bit per pixel ... and thats why  you have only 15000 bytes per 120000 pixels ... so you should: **set bit for each pixel if it is greater then some treshhold ...** ... fx if e-paper would be 8x8 for [smile face like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgK1k.png) you should send 8 sowed values

Comment: What is the resolution of the e-paper screen? 120000/8=15000.

Comment: @Selvin just to confirm if I understood it correctly. You proposed to check luminance of each pixels and set the bit according to it, let's say less then 128 = 0 and more than 128 = 1, do that for the 8 pixels and convert the binary to hex/byte?

Comment: @blackapps It's 400x300, so 400 * 300 / 8 = 15000

Comment: @brmbrm yes....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Selvin suggested I should have checked each pixel by the treshold and converted the binary to hex/byte. Here is the working version:

```
fun convertPictureToByteArray(bitmap: Bitmap): ByteArray {
        val byteArray = ByteArray(15000)
        var index = 0
        var temp = 0

        val pixels = IntArray(bitmap.width * bitmap.height)
        bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.width, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height)
        for(x in (bitmap.height - 1) downTo 0) {
            for(y in 0 until bitmap.width / 8) {
                var tempBinary = ""
                for(z in 0 until 8) {
                    val red = Color.red(pixels[temp])
                    val green = Color.green(pixels[temp])
                    val blue = Color.blue(pixels[temp])

                    val luminance = 0.299 * red + 0.587 * green + 0.114 * blue
                    if(luminance < 128)
                        tempBinary += "0"
                    else
                        tempBinary += "1"
                    temp++
                }
                val decimalValue = Integer.parseInt(tempBinary, 2)
                val hexValue = decimalValue.toString(16).toUpperCase()
                byteArray[index] = hexValue.toInt(16).toByte()
                index++
            }
        }

        return byteArray
    }
```

Comment: `byteArray[index] = Byte.parseByte(tempBinary, 2)` should be enough ...

Comment: and of course you may also take a advantage that insted `tempBinary` you may just sum of `(luminance < 128 ? 0 : 1) * Math.Pow(2, z)` like in [this C# code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/voYv2N)

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion to use bit manipulation instead of concatenating and parsing Strings. It should be significantly faster, considering you're running this for every pixel in an image. You can use the `repeat` function for more simply iterating a range where you don't need the iteration index variable. Also, there's a `Color.luminance` utility function.

```
fun convertPictureToByteArray(bitmap: Bitmap): ByteArray {
    val byteArray = ByteArray(15000)
    var index = 0
    var temp = 0

    val pixels = IntArray(bitmap.width * bitmap.height)
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.width, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height)
    repeat(pixels.size / 8) {
        var tempBinary = 0
        repeat(8) {
            tempBinary = (tempBinary shl 1) or Color.luminance(pixels[temp++]).roundToInt()
        }
        byteArray[index++] = tempBinary.toByte()
    }

    return byteArray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to convert a bitmap into a byte array and then display it on an e-paper display, you would typically follow these steps:

1. **Convert the Bitmap to a Byte Array**:

   You can convert a `Bitmap` into a byte array in Android using the following method:

   ```java
   public byte[] bitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
       ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
       return stream.toByteArray();
   }
   ```

   The above code compresses the bitmap into a PNG format, but you can change the format to JPEG or WEBP if needed. The quality is set to 100, meaning no compression, but this can also be adjusted if you need a smaller byte array.
2. **Send the Byte Array to the E-Paper Display**:

   This step depends on how you're interfacing with the e-paper display. If you're using a library or an SDK provided by the e-paper manufacturer, there might be a specific method to send image data to the display.

   Make sure to refer to the documentation for your specific e-paper display model or the SDK you're using.
3. **Display the Byte Array as an Image on the E-Paper Display**:

   Once the byte array has been sent to the e-paper display, you'll need to execute the appropriate command(s) to render the image. Again, this will depend on the specifics of the e-paper display and any associated libraries or SDKs.

   For many e-paper displays, you might need to convert the image to a 1-bit bitmap (black & white with no grays) depending on the display's capabilities. Some e-paper displays support grayscale or even full color, but many are monochrome.

   Make sure to understand the capabilities and requirements of your e-paper display to ensure the image displays correctly.

**Note**: When working with e-paper displays, refreshing or updating the display can be relatively slow compared to traditional screens. This is a characteristic of e-paper technology. Ensure your application or use case takes this into account to avoid user frustration or potential issues with rapid screen updates.